# What's the name of this walking style used by Luna Lovegood?

Tags: word-usage

There is a character called "Luna Lovegood" in Harry Potter series
This is how she walks:

[image]

What's the name of this walking style used by this character?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

That is an example of [**skipping**](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/skip#Verb): *To move by hopping on alternate feet.*

See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ucvifij6ZHA) or [this one](https://youtu.be/jY_0EehySCY?t=28) for examples. They are being quite "large" in their movements for demonstration purposes; the clip you posted shows less-pronounced knee movements but it is still skipping.

Comment: I learned this word from Rebecca Meyer's [euology](https://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2017/06/12/eulogy-completed/). #663399